# Puppet: Create directory on nfs share with root_squash set

Tags: puppet, permissions

I have an NFS share on a server, that belongs to user `barack`. `barack` can write in this share, and `root` can't, because of the [root squash feature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_security#Root_squash)

I tried creating a directory for `barack` on the share with puppet 2.7.21, using the [`file`](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#file) type, but it looks like puppet creates files/directories as root, and then changes the ownership. Obviously, the first step will (and does) fail.

I ended up using `exec` w/ `mkdir`.

Is my theory about puppet creating files as root first right? Is there a way to force puppet to create a directory as `barack`, using the `file` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disregard my below answer, I initially misunderstood.. This is apparently a bug.  http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/14681

Yeah, use the owner parameter to the fie type
`file { $your_dir_here:
    ensure => "directory",
     owner => "barack"
}`